# Why is await not waiting

Tags: dart

In the following, I would expect:

This output:

```
Start sleep1
End sleep1
Start sleep2
End sleep2
```

But I get output:

```
Start sleep1
Start sleep2
End sleep1
End sleep2
```

Code:

```
Future printSleep1() async{
  print('Start sleep1');
  return await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => print('End sleep1'));
}

Future printSleep2() async{
  print('Start sleep2');
  return new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => print('End sleep2'));
}

main() {
    printSleep1();
  printSleep2();
}
```

Also when not returning a `Future`:

```
printSleep1() async{
  print('Start sleep1');
  await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => print('End sleep1'));
}

printSleep2() async{
  print('Start sleep2');
  new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => print('End sleep2'));
}

main() {
    printSleep1();
  printSleep2();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `printSleep1` and `printSleep2` return Futures, so they don't necessarily start execution when you call them. (Dart 2 changes this subtly, in that they execute up to the first await, but that's not relevant here.)

Change you main to:

```
main() async {
  await printSleep1();
  await printSleep2();
}
```

so that printSleep2 won't get called until after printSleep1's Future completes.

Comment: I get the same even if not returning a Future?

Comment: As soon as you mark a method with `async` it must return a Future (even if you don't declare it). The way you have it written now the compiler is adding `Future<Void>` as the return type for you. See: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async#async-functions-the-fine-print